# Get Current Licence type for SharePoint Farm using C#?

Tags: 2013, development, server-farm, licensing, sharepoint-farm

As the question says,
I want to fetch the license type for my current SharePoint farm in my C# code

i.e.
current license

SharePoint Server with Enterprise Client Access License

I want to get the same value by c# code.

Comment: What version of SharePoint do you want this for - 2007, 2010, 2013?

Comment: i want this for 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop Farm products:

```
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration;
// .... class...
SPFarm farm = SPFarm.Local;
foreach (Guid prd in farm.Products)
{
    if (prd == new Guid("B7D84C2B-0754-49E4-B7BE-7EE321DCE0A9"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise");
    }
}
```

[SP version Guid](http://blog.fpweb.net/how-to-find-your-sharepoint-version-in-ten-seconds-flat-with-powershell/)